# Reformatting a LaTeX document by perl

Tags: perl

I have a `LaTeX` document in which the modifications in the text and equations are done in red color in order for them to be distinguished from unmodified text:

```
{\color{red} MODIFIED TEXT OR EQUATION GOES HERE.}
```

This modification can be a single word, a phrase, a sentence, a paragraph, or an equation. For example:

```
 \pi \rho \hat{\bf x} \int\omega_{\color{red} \theta}
```

or

```
{\color{red} This work presents the ``numerical study'' of convection in vertical annuli;}
```

How can I write a `perl` one-liner which can replace `{\color{red} MODIFIED TEXT OR EQUATION GOES HERE.}` to `MODIFIED TEXT OR EQUATION GOES HERE.`? I mean to remove `{\color{red}` and the right curly brace `}` throughout the entire `LaTeX` document.

Comment: A more sensible approach to this is to replace \color{red} with a macro. Then you can just redefine this macro as your see fit. In your latter case, with a blank. The braces most of the time are not functional, so I would not worry about them.

Comment: Do you mean: `\newcommand{\modifcmd}[1]{\color{red} #1}`?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes. Generally strategies that take advantage of the fact that TeX/LaTex are programming languages, albeit unconventional ones, are more robust and effective than alternatives that rely for example on text manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/{\\color{red}(.*)}/\1/g' filename
```

explanation of the flags(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6302045/330830):

> -p: Places a printing loop around your command so that it acts on each line of standard input. Used mostly so Perl can beat the pants off awk
> in terms of power AND simplicity :-)
>
> -e: Allows you to provide the program as an argument rather than in a file. You don't want to have to create a script file for every little
> Perl one-liner.
>
> -i: Modifies your input file in-place (making a backup of the original). Handy to modify files without the {copy, delete-original,
> rename} process.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ echo "{\color{red} MODIFIED TEXT OR EQUATION GOES HERE.}" | \
perl -pe 's/\{\\color\{red\} (.*?)\}/$1/g'
MODIFIED TEXT OR EQUATION GOES HERE.
```